# \input{} command inside custom .sty package

Tags: input

Here's my setup :

- Two PCs (one desktop and one laptop)
- Two installations of Texmaker and MikTex (exactly the same versions)

i've created my own package (.sty file) and this package uses external files (that are located in the same directory as the pacakge. the files are added via the \input{...} command

I've used the package for quite a while on both PCs flawlessly and now the laptop throws an error at compilation (of the document which uses the package)

```
LaTeX Error: File 'basic_packages.tex' not found. Type X...
```

I've managed to understand what's going on :

- The desktop interprets "\input{...}" as "go look for the file **at the package's directory**
- the laptop looks for the file **at the document's directory**. Of course i want the included file to stay with the package.

Here are my codes (simplified)

**package**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{sdlibV1}[14/03/2019 custom package]

\newif\if@all\@allfalse
\DeclareOption{all}{\@alltrue}


\ProcessOptions\relax


\input{basic_packages} %<-- this input
%\input{basic_macros} also not useful for the question

\if@all
%stuff, not useful here
\fi

\endinput
```

**basic_packages.tex**

```
\RequirePackage[table,dvipsnames,named]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{array}
```

**Document**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sdlibV1}% <-- package loaded here

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\subfile{calcul_integral}% I've tried removing those, and only using "hello world"
\subfile{algebre_lineaire}
\subfile{equations_differentielles}
\end{document}
```

Paths of files :

**Document** : \HEIG-VD\Cours\Math2\Notes

**sdlibV1.sty and basic_packages.text** : \HEIG-VD\Notes\LaTex\packages\tex\latex\sdlibV1

(The packages folderhas been configured correctly as a package "source")
What i've also tried :

- Checking pdflatex's command
- Using a temp document (standalone, without anything in it, just a "hello world")
- using \include command (did not work at all)
- putting all my included files (16 elements) inside the .sty file, it worked but it's absolutely disgusting

Comment: Where are these files placed in the file system in relation to each other?

Comment: the "document" file is anyhwere (doesn't really matter) the library and included file are in a dedicated folder. (which has been made so that it's recognized as a library)

Comment: Note that LaTeX does not really have a notion of libraries, so please explain **exactly** what you have done.

Comment: yeah sorry, i'm still a bit new so the vocab hadn't time to sink in that much. I've created a **.sty** file (sdlibV1.sty) and i've used the **\usepackage{sdlibV1}** to "load" it. So it's more of a package than a library i guess (i tend to get confused coming from C programming)

Comment: I understand that, but where is sdlibV1 and basic_packages.tex located in relation to everything else? And why the `\input` why not just add that contents of that into the sty file, less file locations to worry about

Comment: If sdlibV1.sty and basic_packages.tex are in the same folder they normally should both by found. Did you update the FNDB or run mktexlsr after adding the tex-file?

Comment: @daleif I've put the paths of the files in my question. Concerning the choice of the "\input{}" it's for clarity purposes, like i've said i've tried it and it worked. (The included files are supposed to be easily edited).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have no idea what that is, i'll try to run mktexlsr and edit my message (i don't know about FNDB)

Comment: just saw that you have miktex. Then you need to update the FNDB (in the miktex console, user mode, menu tasks, or with `initexmf -u` on the command line.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i've run the command : it didn't change anything
I've run mktexlsr : it didn't change anything either

Comment: How did you add the packages folder as a new root? As user or as admin? In the second case you probably need to run the console as admin and then call the renew FNDB task.

Comment: I've used the mo_admin to add the root folder. Also i've done everything as admin

Comment: probably unrelated but `14/03/2019 ` is an error: it should be `2019/03/14` or better unless you need to support old releases `2019-03-14`

Comment: It worked ! i don't know what exactly, but it seems that the `initexmf -u` did the job (i've re-run the command, with the `--admin` argument)

Comment: so presumably you added the .sty file updated FNDB (otherwise that would not be found) then added the .tex file without updating, so it is not found.

Comment: It seems like it. Weird since i've updated both files countless times and it worked each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved !

After changes to a package (and/or files included by it) the following command in the MikTex console (ran **as admin**)

```
initexmf -u --admin
```

Comment: you only need to do this if you _add_ new files, not if you change/edit an existing file.